# Issue with ctypes bitfields

Tags: python, ctypes, bit-fields

In this example, I get a weird behavior with `ctypes` where each `c_bool` field seems to be bigger than 1 bit.

```
import ctypes

class Bitfield(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
            ("a", ctypes.c_uint16, 16),
            ("b", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("c", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("d", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("e", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("f", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("g", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("h", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("i", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("j", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("k", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("l", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("m", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("n", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("o", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
            ("p", ctypes.c_bool, 1),
        ]

    def getdict(self):
        dict((f, getattr(self.bit, f)) for f, _, _ in self.bit._fields_)

class Status(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [
            ("all",              ctypes.c_long),
            ("bit",              Bitfield),            
        ]

a = Status(0x20281234)
print hex(a.all) # Will display 0x20281234

a.bit.b = True   
print hex(a.all) # Should display 0x20291234, but display 0x20011234

a = Status(0x0)
print hex(a.all) # Will display 0x00000000

a.bit.b = True   
print hex(a.all) # Should display 0x0010000, and display 0x0010000
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The set and get functions of `c_bool`, i.e. [`bool_set`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l718) and `bool_get`, aren't designed for bitfields. It's setting the entire byte to either 1 or 0. You can use `c_uint8` instead.

Comment: @eryksun Ok. It works with `c_uint8`. How to know if `c_uint16` or `c_float` will work with it?

Comment: integer fields support bitfields. This excludes `c_float` and `c_double` from use directly in bitfields, but you can use a union with an integer field.

Comment: This is very confusing. I would be glad to get a summary or a link to the doc.

Comment: The docs say that "[f]or integer type fields like `c_int`, a third optional item can be given. It must be a small positive integer defining the bit width of the field." C only specifies bitfields for integer types, not floating point types, which is what ctypes implements -- except it doesn't support the C99 `bool` type in bitfields. CPython still targets C89, so I suppose no one has thought to modernize `bool_set` and `bool_get`.